# How can i insert new json object to existing json file (in the middle of object)

Tags: python, json, append

filejson.json

```
{"Fiksi":[
    {
    "judul":"fiksi1",
    "pengarang":"pengarang1",
    "file":"namafiksi1.txt"
    },
    {
    "judul":"fiksi2",
    "pengarang":"pengarang2",
    "file":"namafiksi2.txt"
    }
],
"Non-Fiksi":[
    {
    "judul":"nonfiksi1",
    "penulis":"penulis1",
    "file":"namanonfiksi1.txt"
    },
    {
    "judul":"nonfiksi2",
    "penulis":"penulis2",
    "file":"namanonfiksi2.txt"
    }
]
```

I want to insert new object on tag "Fiksi". so the item can insert in the middle of file json.
The object like this :

```
item = {"judul":"fiksi3", "pengarang":"pengarang3","file":"namafiksi3.txt"}
```

my code now :

```
config = json.loads(open('filejson.json').read())
with open('filejson.json','a') as f:
    data = f["Fiksi"].append(item)
    json.dumps(data)
```

its not working

Answer (score 6):

Step1: Read data

```
config = json.loads(open('filejson.json').read())
```

Step2: Update data (in python object)

```
config["Fiksi"].append(item)
```

Step3: Write all data (not append) back to file

```
with open('filejson.json','w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(config))
```

On a side note, you can use [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) and [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump) instead for `json.loads` and `json.dumps` when dealing with files, so it will be

```
with open('filejson.json', 'r') as f:
    config = json.load(f)
config["Fiksi"].append(item)
with open('filejson.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(config, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to work with python objects:

- import json
- Load your file with json.load
- Insert in the loaded dict
- Dump to a file with json.dump

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
f.write(json.dumps(data))
```